# Kill a future completely after some time

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `future` that does some intensive task. I call that `future` with a timeout. If it times out, I throw an exception back to client as well as create another `scheduledfuture` to cancel first `future` eventually after a while. The idea is to give sometime after initial timeout for `future` to complete its task, but if it doesn't complete in that time, just kill it.

My code looks like

```
try {
    return future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (TimeoutException) {
   //create a scheduledfuture here which waits for another 5s
   // and kill the above future is it is still not done
   //the callable of scheduledfuture looks like -
   /*
   if (!future.isDone()) {
       future.cancel(true);
   }
   */
}
```

Now two questions here -
1. The `future.cancel(true)` will just set the interrupt flag to true. It will not end the task as it is. How should I end the task? Is there a JVM process internally that checks threads for interrupted flag and terminates them if true?
2. As the interrupted flag is now set, after the task completes, is there a process that resets the flag? Else that thread managed through `ExecutorService` will fail with `InterruptedException` when it tries to take up next request which contains a blocking call.

Comment: The task is responsible for exiting gracefully if it receives an InterruptedException or observes its interrupted flag to be true.  If it doesn’t do this, there is nothing you can do to stop it;  it is a rogue thread.

Comment: I checked, the task indeed handles interruption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I end the task?

Run the task is a separate process and kill the process to stop it. There is no safe way to stop a thread in Java, unless the task has been coded to support it.

> As the interrupted flag is now set after the task completes, is there a process that resets the flag?

Yes, the ExecutorService resets the interrupted flag.